# How to implement some commands on starting iex session?

Tags: command-line-interface, elixir, elixir-iex

Let say I want to implement a few commands on starting iex in root path of my project, like:

```
Logger.configure(level: :info)
require Ecto.Query
alias MyApp.User
# and so on
```

And I want to implement all of these commands on every starting of iex automatically. Another thing I want - is to make this setting only for one project (for example, I wouldn't have `MyApp.User` on another project, so I don't need to use it accross all iex of the system). How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your project root create a file called `.iex.exs` and add the commands there. That should do the trick.