# How do I import/alias things when IEx starts?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my mix project, I often have to `alias` and `import` various things every time I start Iex.

Is there a place to put these standard commands so I don't have to type them every time?

It's a `phoenix` project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement some commands on starting iex session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207301/how-to-implement-some-commands-on-starting-iex-session)

Comment: [Import project module into IEX session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56178790/import-project-module-into-iex-session)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an `.iex.exs` file in your project directory - the file will be evaluated when you open `iex`. For example:

```
# iex.exs

alias MyProject.Repo
alias MyProject.Schema, as: S

import Ecto.Query
```

You can read more in the [docs on .iex.exs](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-the-iex-exs-file)